# Flutter App Play Store not listing as installed

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app that I have built and tested. I have tested by installing locally on my test device. I have published my app to the play store however when you install the app from the play store it does not show in the list of installed apps and as such dose not prompt for updates when they are issued. What have I missed?